# VSCode (or other tool) auto add <sup> tags to reference numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, automation, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I often have to copy large pharma or legal text and translate them for use on the web - either through a CMS or through direct code. Sometimes these documents are really large. Now when I copy the text and paste into VSCode (or sublime, or the CMS etc) it generally pastes everything as striaght text without the formatting (which is great). The problem is I often have 5-100+ reference numbers that need <sup>'ing.

I could write a small php / js script to do this, but unsure of the exact regex and not knowing how to write VSCode extensions, is there something out there that might do this.

I could either do 'all numbers' get that treatment [0-9], or for bonus points only numbers that come after a full stop. Or for a full on bonus new car, the complete regex would be numbers that appear after a full stop OR are at the end of the line. Ie

```
Some text1,2
Some text.1,2,3
Some other text.1,2,24 Lets carry on writing
```

Would all get caught. But I'd be happy at just capturing all the numbers if thats easier.

Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXBynB/5).

I added a few other cases, you can see what matched and what didn't.  Let me know if I guessed wrong on what should be a match or not.

```
(\.(\d,?)+)|((\d,?)+)$
```

> Digits with/without commas after a period

OR

> digits with/without comma at end of line

Replace with `$1$3<sup>`